# App based Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I plan to make an app based rails site. The rails webapplication should only have authentication and the rest of the functionality are "apps".
The basic idea is that users in the future could develop their own functions.

What is the best soultion for this? Should i write my apps as a plugin or gem?
Point me in right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines)

ps - whilst the railscast is rails2.3, you can find your own way to more modern practices from there - [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is a good gem which is written as an engine and does some of the stuff you probably want your code to do - have a look inside it's source for more info and google "rails 3" & "engines" for more info, i'm not so clued up on it myself

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. But the railscast is written in rails 2.3 and maybe something has changed?

Comment: @Timmie Sarjanen, i agree that the railscast is out of date but it's the ideal that counts here - you now know that engines are the way to do this. I personally can't ever imagine not being able to take something out of a railscast, regardless of the version of rails it focuses on because Ryan Bates always gives you some gold. Hopefully someone will post rails3 links to save you googling for them